# Magento Connect extension error. Mage_tar_archive tar.php

Tags: extensions

I have a very odd problem here and i have been trying to figure out what's wrong.
When i try to install a extension on my magento im running now on version 1.8.1

I'll get this error output Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Archive_Tar' not found in public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Archive.php on line 88

What i've noticed when checking further on the problem is that my Tar.php file get's removed, when trying to ftp it back up again in the right directory it just gets removed once again after trying to install a extension once again. Anyone who knows what thous problem could be because of ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To state the obvious, which is seems like you already know, you're seeing this error because you're missing the class definition files for `Mage_Archive_Tar`.

> What i've noticed when checking further on the problem is that my Tar.php file get's removed, when trying to ftp it back up again in the right directory it just gets removed once again after trying to install a extension once again. Anyone who knows what thous problem could be because of ?

There's a few things that come to mind here.

1. Your hosting provider (you didn't mention who they are) may have some sort of security audit software running that's removing the file
2. You have a deployment setup where there's actually multiple front-end web servers, but you're not using a shared NFS mount between them.  This means you upload `Tar.php` to one server, but since it's not on the others your still fail, and FTP is connecting in some sort of round robin way
3. Your system has some sort of continuos deployment running that's moving files from place X (a source control repository or staging server) to place Y (your production server), and removing any changes.

I'd poke around your Unix cron jobs, as well as any custom Magento cron jobs installed by extensions.  It's possible (although not likely) that something in there is deleting the file on a regular basis as well. I'd also try putting different files in the same folder and seeing if they vanish to narrow things down.

Good luck!